# Akka HTTP custom headers: error in documentation or unfamiliar syntax?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am reading [this part](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/http-model.html) of the documentation of Akka HTTP

In the subsection about custom headers there are these code snippets:

```
final class ApiTokenHeader(token: String) extends ModeledCustomHeader[ApiTokenHeader] {
  override def renderInRequests = false
  override def renderInResponses = false
  override val companion = ApiTokenHeader
  override def value: String = token
}
object ApiTokenHeader extends ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion[ApiTokenHeader] {
  override val name = "apiKey"
  override def parse(value: String) = Try(new ApiTokenHeader(value))
}
```

and

```
val ApiTokenHeader(t1) = ApiTokenHeader("token")
t1 should ===("token")
```

I believe that `ApiTokenHeader` must be a `case class` instead of `class` in order such value declaration with binding to be valid: `val ApiTokenHeader(t1) = ApiTokenHeader("token")`

Is this correct or I miss some knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct. The reason `ApiTokenHeader` in the example works as shown is because it extends [`ModeledCustomHeader`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.11/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/ModeledCustomHeader.html) and its companion object extends [`ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.11/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion.html). The implementation of `ModeledCustomHeader` and `ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion` enables the syntax in the example.

From the Scaladoc for `ModeledCustomHeader`:

> Support class for building user-defined custom headers defined by implementing name and value. By implementing a `ModeledCustomHeader` instead of `CustomHeader` directly, all needed `unapply` methods are provided for this class, such that it can be pattern matched on from `RawHeader` and the other way around as well.

From the Scaladoc for `ModeledCustomHeaderCompanion`:

> To be extended by companion object of a custom header extending `ModeledCustomHeader`. Implements necessary `apply` and `unapply` methods to make the such defined header feel "native".

You can check out the source code for both [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.11/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/headers/headers.scala) and `ModeledCustomHeaderSpec` (which uses `ApiTokenHeader`) [here](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.11/akka-http-tests/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/ModeledCustomHeaderSpec.scala).